Don't understand template parameter that is a function call
I'm trying to understand some template code.
I have reduced the code down to the bare essentials. But I don't understand the meaning of the template parameter provided to the function mangledName().
 #include <string_view>

 struct MYS
 {
     int data = 345;
 };

 namespace TA
 {
     extern MYS externalX;

     struct ptr_tX final
     {
         const int& ptr;
     };

     constexpr auto get_ptrX(MYS& t) noexcept
     {
         auto& p0 = t.data;
         return ptr_tX{p0};
     }

     template <auto Type>
     std::string_view mangledName()
     {
         return "Stuff";
     }
 }

 int main()
 {
     // Here we are calling `mangledName()`
     // But the call `get_ptrX()` is done to get the template parameter
     // So I "think" this is done at compile time.
     // But I don't understand what is being given as the parameter.
     //     Is it the type of the result?
     //     Is it the type of the function?
     //     Neither seem to be true and I don't understand what is going on.
     //     I can't seem to manually validate it. The `<auto Type>` is totally confusing me.
     std::string_view key = TA::mangledName<TA::get_ptrX(TA::externalX)>();
 }

For some context: This code in its full form is being used to build field names as string_view at compile time (in this case, data in MYS).  But I have removed this part of it as it is not part of what I am trying to understand. This is used to help generate a JSON parser.

There's a lot to grasp here. Don't try this, if you're not an expert. Short description is generic function to get the fieldnames as you mentioned. The address of an external static object is a compile time constant that's resolved by the linker. But constexpr context requires a workaround at compile-time(prior to linker invocation). Thus most platform use mangled field names as temporary place holders. The "stuff" that you downvalued is generally sth like std::source_location::current(). function_name or __pretty_function__ or sth, which is later filtered and trimmed on both ends.

Despite the name, Type is in fact a non-type template parameter. The call TA::get_ptrX(TA::externalX) is evaluated at compile time: the result is an instance of ptr_tX with ptr reference initialized to refer to externalX.data. This object becomes the non-type template parameter to mangledName. The point of this exercise escapes me.

auto Type here means "non-type template parameter of arbitrary type". Both the value and the type of the parameter are specified or deduced when the template is instantiated. It's perhaps unfortunate that the author of the code named the parameter Type when it's not in fact a type.

@Red.Wave Yes this is exactly what is happening. The original code uses __pretty_function__ (macros for other values on some other compilers).

@IgorTandetnik : Sorry, it was me that set the Type name as I was simplifying the code.

@IgorTandetnik The point of this exercise escapes me.: The library Glaze I am trying to understand auto generates JSON parser and serializer simply using the type info (this includes the JSON field names). I have stripped away much of the code to show the part I don't understand.

The mangledName function is supposed to return its own name; that name contains the template arguments too. Since the argument is replaced with drop-in pre-link id, that id is present in the character string. Thus by proper trimming, the id is obtained.

in this declaration
template <auto Type>
std::string_view mangledName()

auto in the template parameters is a non-type template parameter. and this is C++20 literal class non-type template parameters, C++20 adds the ability to have non-type template parameters that satisfy being a literal class type. (basically any struct that can be constexpr)
TA::externalX is an extern struct that contains an int, its address is known at link time, get_ptrX(TA::externalX) gets this address and initializes a constexpr ptr_tX struct with this address, as the address is constant, it is equivalent to a constant pointer, and can be hashed by the compiler, you then get the equivalent of
static int a;

constexpr ptr_tX b{a};

TA::mangledName<b>();


because the compiler needs to work before the linker and doesn't have the actual address of the object, the compiler encodes it for the linker into the resulting function name, which you can get by __PRETTY_FUNCTION__
template <auto Type>
std::string_view mangledName()
{
    return __PRETTY_FUNCTION__;
}

and on gcc you get.
std::string_view TA::mangledName() [with auto Type = ptr_tX{((const int&)(& externalX.MYS::data))}; std::string_view = std::basic_string_view<char>]

note that the externalX.MYS::data is in the name of the function, which is used to get the name of the class and its members as
a string_view at compile-time.

Thanks. Reading: 13.4.3 Template non-type arguments [temp.arg.nontype]

Because externalX is an extern. The name of the field "MYS.data" is being encoded into the type (presumably to be resolved at link time) , but because we are not using it (apart from getting the pretty name of the function) we can now manipulate it at compile time.
